# Can a static c function return a local char array?

Tags: c, string, return, string-literals, storage-duration

In zflog library I saw this code

```
static char* lvl_char(const int lvl)
{
    switch (lvl)
    {
    case ZF_LOG_VERBOSE:
        return "VERBOSE\0";
    case ZF_LOG_DEBUG:
        return "DEBUG\0";
    case ZF_LOG_INFO:
        return "INFO\0";
    case ZF_LOG_WARN:
        return "WARN\0";
    case ZF_LOG_ERROR:
        return "ERROR\0";
    case ZF_LOG_FATAL:
        return "FATAL\0";
    default:
        ASSERT_UNREACHABLE("Bad log level");
        return "?\0";
    }
}
```

which seemed odd to me. Can we really return a local c string from static functions?

Comment: [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237759/6102) might be of help for understanding where variables are allocated. It was written with microcontrollers in mind, but applies universally. (Except on a PC you don't have true ROM.)

Comment: `"VERBOSE\0"` is odd. Just `"VERBOSE"` is normally sufficient because when the compiler allocates space for strings it includes a NUL termination character. (Unless the caller needs 2 NULs for some crazy reason).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are wrong, the returned pointer is not pointing to a local `char array`, but to a `string literal`, that is `static` for the process.

From [c-standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.4.5 String literals**
>
> **Sematics**
>
> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
> character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.78) **The multibyte character
> sequence is then used to initialize an array of static storage duration** and length just
> sufficient to contain the sequence.[...]

<sup>Emèphasis mine</sup>

Answer (score 7):

The linkage of the *function* (here static) doesn't matter at all. Neither is a "string" returned; instead what is returned is a pointer to char. It is perfectly legal to return pointers to the first character of string literals - the string literals are guaranteed to exist for the whole duration of the program. [C11 6.4.5p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) states that the string literals as they're used here are used to initialize *"an [anonymous] array of **static** storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence". Static storage duration means that its *"lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup."* ([C11 6.2.4p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p3)).

---

The thing that *does* look odd is the `\0` at the end of the string literals, as literal strings are always 0-terminated, so essentially `"VERBOSE\0"` would be just terminated with 2 zero bytes instead of usual one; `strlen` for that string would return `7` just as it would return for `"VERBOSE"`, and so on.

Comment: Will not this char pointer be dangling pointer after the function returns? I mean, aren;'t those strings local?

Comment: @ozgur 1) they are string "literals" 2) there's nothing local, literals have static storage duration.

Answer (score 3):

> *Can a static c function return a local char array?*

**TL;DR** Irrespective of `static` or `extern`, functions should not return a local array because it cannot be used meaningfully.

---

Now, to elaborate the question in hand,

> *....static functions?*

You had it there, the `static` is associated with the linkage for the "function", not the *return value or type*.

Here, `static` storage specifier means, the function has internal linkage, i.e., accessible from the translation unit only.

Related `C11`, chapter §6.2.2

> If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage class
>   specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.

OTOH, the `return` statements like

```
return "FATAL\0"; 
return "DEBUG\0"; ///and so on
```

actually return the pointer to the first element of the [***string literal***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal), which are by definition having static storage duration <sup>Note 1</sup>, so the return value is

- matched with the return type, `char *` <sup>Note 2</sup>
- valid after the return statement. <sup>Note 3</sup>

---

Note 1:

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.5/ P6

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
>   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.<sup>78)</sup> The multibyte character
>   sequence is then used to **initialize an array of static storage duration** and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For **character string literals, the array elements have
>   type `char`**, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character
>   sequence.

Note 2:

Quoting chapter §6.3.2.1/P3,

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object** and is not an lvalue.

Note 3:

Quoting chapter §6.2.4/P3

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
>   _Thread_local, and either with external or internal linkage or **with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program** and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

Answer (score 2):

- Can a static c function return a local char array? No, that leads to undefined behavior.
- Does your code return a local char array? No. It returns a pointer to a string literal, which resides in read-only memory. This memory is not local.
- Can you return a pointer to a string literal from any function? Yes.
- Is there a difference between regular functions a internal linkage `static` ones here? No.